# Delete same line on multiple file

Tags: html, delete-file

I want to delete the same line on multiple file (58 html files!)

Exemple, to delete from all file the lines 56 to 305 and 314 to 320.

How to go?

Comment: I would go with a c# console app. Would take about 5 minutes to code. Don't know if there is faster way. (Assuming all files are in the same folder). I can post the code if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# one time program. (You can get Visual community for free)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DelteLines
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dir = @"<your path to html files>";
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.html", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            var excludeRanges = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            excludeRanges.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(56, 305));
            excludeRanges.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(314, 320));
            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
                var newLines = new List<string>();
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
                {
                    var lNumber = i + 1; //Assuming you count from 1 and not from 0 your lines
                    var toExclude = excludeRanges.Where(x => lNumber >= x.Item1 && lNumber <= x.Item2).Any();
                    if (toExclude)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    newLines.Add(lines[i]);
                }
                File.WriteAllLines(f, newLines);
            }
        }
    }
}
```